# How to store a fraction as a character in MySQL so it can be outputted within text

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, character, fractions

I am trying to store the fraction 3/5 (three fifths) as a character in MySQL so that it outputs in php like the symbol ½ within a line of text. I am using phpMyAdmin.

The code for the fraction 3/5 is:

- Character Name - VULGAR FRACTION 3/5
- Character - ⅗
- Entity --
- Num Entity - `&#8535;`
- Hex Entity - `&#x2157;`

Is there a way to do this.

Comment: You could just store the entity number and output that.

Comment: What is preventing you from storing a character in one of your database tables?

Comment: I can store '½' easily enough but '⅗' comes out as '?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a long answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) that explains what you need. Basically you need to make sure all your tables are using utf-8 encoding. It will take some debugging.

Comment: Thanks @nathanhayfield that worked and solved the problem, Ted